# Euler ODE - particular solution problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE: $$x^2y'' -xy' +y = 6x\ln(x)$$

Once I solve the homogenous part I get that $$y_h = xC_1 + x\ln(x)C_2$$

But I am having problems with the particular solution. When I try to find it using variation of constants:

$$C_1'x + C_2'x\ln(x)=0$$
$$C_1' + C_2'(1+\ln(x))=6x\ln(x)$$

The Wronskian is $x$ and if I solve the system of equations I get that $C_1'=-6x\ln^2(x)$ and $C_2' = 6x\ln(x)$

If I integrate both and plug them in the upper solution and add them, I get $$\frac{3x^3(\ln(x)+1)}{2} + C_1x + C_2x\ln(x)$$

The solution provided by Wolfram Alpha is $$C_1x + C_2x\ln(x)+x\ln^3(x)$$

Where did I go wrong? I solved the system of equations and I checked it on symbolab, I got $C_1$ and $C_2$ correctly. What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you integrate $-6 \ln^2(x)/x$ and $6 \ln(x)/x$ because you divide out the Wronskian, but also divide by the leading $x^2$? In fact, to get the ODE in the right form,  it is better to write the ODE as $$y'' - \dfrac{y'}{x} + \dfrac{y}{x^2} = \dfrac{6 \ln(x)}{x}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the homogeneous and Wronskian correct.

We have

$$y'' - \dfrac{y'}{x} + \dfrac{y}{x^2} = \dfrac{6 \ln(x)}{x}$$

Using [*Variation of Parameters*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx) (notice that the form to apply VoP is $y'' + \ldots$), from the homogeneous solution and ODE, we have

$$y_1 = x, y_2 = x \ln(x), f(x) = \dfrac{6 \ln(x)}{x}$$

So, we get

$$\begin{align} w_1 &= -\int \dfrac{f(x) y_2}{W}~dx = -\int \dfrac{6 \ln^2(x)}{x}~dx = - 2 \ln^3(x) \\ w_2 &= \int \dfrac{f(x) y_1}{W}~dx = \int \dfrac{6 \ln(x)}{x}~dx = 3 \ln^2(x) \end{align}$$

The solution is given by

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_1 w_1(x) + y_2 w_2(x)$$

Comment: +1 nice moo ...

Comment: I never knew I had to divide the equation by the leading coefficient. Why is that? Truth be told, I used this method for solving ODEs with constant coefficients (no x variable multiplying the derivatives of y).

Comment: @johndoe: Look at the form in the blue box at https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx. Notice how it "must" be in the form $y''...$ for the generalized approach to work. That is what caused your issue and is a typical problem.

Comment: I absolutely never knew about this. I could have easily brushed it off as a typo in my workbook because it's prone to having mistakes. Thanks though!